# C++ how to add two numbers in decimal system?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have two numbers 999 and 2. I want to add them in the decimal system, ex:

```
999
 +2
---
1001
```

First, I am adding 2 with 9 and I'm getting 11 so I'm printing 1 and carrying out 1 for next 9. Similarly getting 10, printing 0 and carrying out 1 for next 9 and adding them. It's like how we used to do addition in our school level. However, now I have to do the same in C++. For this, first I'm splitting 999 and storing in an array. After that adding 2 with the last element of array. If the sum is more than or equal 10, I'm keeping `sum%10` for the next elements in the array. The problem is, I don't know how can I add the `sum%10` with the next elements and keep checking if they are more than or equal 10 at the same time for rest of the elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume `a` and `b` contain digits of numbers in reverse order. This code will add `b` to `a`, i.e. `a = a+b`.

```
int base = 10;
int carry = 0;
for (size_t i=0; i<max(a.size(),b.size()) || carry; ++i) {
    if (i == a.size())
        a.push_back (0);
    a[i] += carry + (i < b.size() ? b[i] : 0);
    carry = a[i] >= base;
    if (carry)  a[i] -= base;
}
```